# Is there a way to intercept every single IRP in KMDF

Tags: windows, driver, kmdf

I am writing a KMDF driver that needs to intercept every IRP before it passes to the ioQueue.

I have a callback function registered PreprocessIrpCallback and want to hook it into the framework like this

```
status = WdfDeviceInitAssignWdmIrpPreprocessCallback(DeviceInit
    , PreprocessIrpCallback
    , ?
    , ?);
```

But what goes in the question marks if I want to intercept every single IRP?

Comment: I don't think this can be done with `WdfDeviceInitAssignWdmIrpPreprocessCallback` as documented. The MajorFunction arg is presumably required (despite an apparent doc bug), and I think the best you could do would be to call this function separately for every major code you care about e.g. from the list here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff550710(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: seems like a design question. Why do you not want the requests to be queued?